# I need a THREE.JS script to save the scene as a 360 image to be used in our work with children, to learn about emotions

Tags: javascript, three.js, runtime-error

I am trying to use a script that was designed for three.js v > 77

Most of the scripts I found and that we can use are older, made with three.js versions 70

I tried to port them to newer versions and it is a nightmare.

The only solution I see it to downgrade the script to save the 360 images to three.js version 70, so I can then save the images and 360 movie directly from the scripts I have.

And I did that - but it does not work.

It gives me "[.Offscreen-For-WebGL-000001D6AAAB0BA0]RENDER WARNING: there is no texture bound to the unit 0" eror.

If I try with version 75, I get two more errors:

"WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: bindTexture: textures can not be used with multiple targets"

I made a jsfiddle for the three.js version 75 because I believe that if this will work, so will the one for version 70.

Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/yh7o4rpz/

The code that gives me the errors:

```
function CubemapToEquirectangular(renderer, provideCubeCamera, resolution) {

var resolution = resolution.toUpperCase() || "4K";

this.width = 1;
this.height = 1;

this.renderer = renderer;

this.material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        map: {
            type: 't',
            value: null
        }
    },
    vertexShader: this.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: this.fragmentShader,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});

this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
this.quad = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 1),
    this.material
);
this.scene.add(this.quad);
this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(1 / -2, 1 / 2, 1 / 2, 1 / -2, -10000, 10000);

this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

this.cubeCamera = null;
this.attachedCamera = null;

if (resolution === "4K") {
    this.setSize(4096, 2048);
}

if (resolution === "2K") {
    this.setSize(2048, 1024);
}

if (resolution === "1K") {
    this.setSize(1024, 512);
}


var gl = this.renderer.getContext();
this.cubeMapSize = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE)

if (provideCubeCamera) {

    if (resolution === "4K") {
        this.getCubeCamera(2048);
    }

    if (resolution === "2K") {
        this.getCubeCamera(1024);
    }

    if (resolution === "1K") {
        this.getCubeCamera(512);
    }
}

}

CubemapToEquirectangular.prototype.vertexShader = `
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec2 uv;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

varying vec2 vUv;

void main()  {

vUv = vec2( 1.- uv.x, uv.y );
gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

}
`;

CubemapToEquirectangular.prototype.fragmentShader = `
precision mediump float;

uniform samplerCube map;

varying vec2 vUv;

#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

void main()  {

vec2 uv = vUv;

float longitude = uv.x * 2. * M_PI - M_PI + M_PI / 2.;
float latitude = uv.y * M_PI;

vec3 dir = vec3(
    - sin( longitude ) * sin( latitude ),
    cos( latitude ),
    - cos( longitude ) * sin( latitude )
);
normalize( dir );

gl_FragColor = vec4( textureCube( map, dir ).rgb, 1. );

}
`;


CubemapToEquirectangular.prototype.setSize = function(width, height) {

this.width = width;
this.height = height;

this.quad.scale.set(this.width, this.height, 1);

this.camera.left = this.width / -2;
this.camera.right = this.width / 2;
this.camera.top = this.height / 2;
this.camera.bottom = this.height / -2;

this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

this.output = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(this.width, this.height, {
    minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    magFilter: THREE.LinearFilter,
    wrapS: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    wrapT: THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping,
    format: THREE.RGBAFormat,
    type: THREE.UnsignedByteType
});

this.canvas.width = this.width;
this.canvas.height = this.height;

}

CubemapToEquirectangular.prototype.getCubeCamera = function(size) {

this.cubeCamera = new THREE.CubeCamera(.1, 10000, Math.min(this.cubeMapSize, size));
return this.cubeCamera;

}

CubemapToEquirectangular.prototype.attachCubeCamera = function(camera) {

this.getCubeCamera();
this.attachedCamera = camera;

}

CubemapToEquirectangular.prototype.convert = function(cubeCamera) {

this.quad.material.uniforms.map.value = cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture;
this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera, this.output, true);

var pixels = new Uint8Array(4 * this.width * this.height);

var gl = this.renderer.getContext();
gl.readPixels(0, 0, this.width, this.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

var imageData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(pixels), this.width, this.height);

this.ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

this.canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {

    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var fileName = 'pano-' + document.title + '-' + Date.now() + '.jpg';
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = url;
    anchor.setAttribute("download", fileName);
    anchor.className = "download-js-link";
    anchor.innerHTML = "downloading...";
    anchor.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    setTimeout(function() {
        anchor.click();
        document.body.removeChild(anchor);
    }, 1);

}, 'image/jpeg');

}

CubemapToEquirectangular.prototype.preBlob = function(cubeCamera) {

var autoClear = this.renderer.autoClear;
this.renderer.autoClear = true;
this.cubeCamera.position.copy(camera.position);
this.cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(this.renderer, scene);
this.renderer.autoClear = autoClear;

this.quad.material.uniforms.map.value = cubeCamera.renderTarget.texture;
this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera, this.output, true);

var pixels = new Uint8Array(4 * this.width * this.height);
var gl = this.renderer.getContext();
gl.readPixels(0, 0, this.width, this.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

var imageData = new ImageData(new Uint8ClampedArray(pixels), this.width, this.height);

this.ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

}


CubemapToEquirectangular.prototype.update = function(camera, scene) {

var autoClear = this.renderer.autoClear;
this.renderer.autoClear = true;
this.cubeCamera.position.copy(camera.position);
this.cubeCamera.updateCubeMap(this.renderer, scene);
this.renderer.autoClear = autoClear;

this.convert(this.cubeCamera);

}
```

PS: I am new to this site and to Three Js so please tell me if I make some mistakes, rather than vote with minus.

Ps: the script I am using to save 360 images comes from here: https://github.com/spite/THREE.CubemapToEquirectangular/blob/master/build/CubemapToEquirectangular.js -

Comment: I used the latest revision in you jsfiddle, using `<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>`. Got some warnings in the console about morphTargets (meshes have a still pose), but pressing `e` key calls the open/save dialog for `pano--1515409595864.jpg` file. The result picture is an equirectangular map.

Comment: Yes, it works with the latest three.js, but not with the version 70 I need for the other scripts. :) Thank you very much for your help. :)